# Entity Framework Error Deleting Objects With Foreign Keys

Tags: c#, database, winforms, linq

I need to delete a contact that an event is already created with, the structure in how the data is saved is as follows

Events Table

[image]

Contacts Table

[image]

I have a separate table called EventContacts that manage the relationship between events and contacts

[image]

The class for Events

```
public class Events
    {

        [Key]
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string title{ get; set; }
        public string desc{ get; set; }
        public virtual List<Contact> contacts{ get; set; }
    }
```

Contacts class

```
public class Contact
    {
        public string ContactId { get; set; }  
        public string name{ get; set; }
        public string email{ get; set; }
    }
```

I remove the contacts using this code

```
using (var db= new DatabaseModel())
{
     Contact contact = db.Contacts.Find(id);
     db.Contact.Remove(contact);
     db.SaveChanges();
}
```

To add an event i use this

```
List<Contact> cons = new List<Contact>();
foreach (ComboItem cmb in cbItems)
{
   EventContact evntConts = new EventContact()
   {
      contId = cmb.contId,
      evntId = eventidevntId
      userId = userId,
    };

    cons.Add(evntConts);
}
UserEvent events = new UserEvent()
{
   eventid= this.evntid,
   title= txt_title.Text,
   description = txt_des.Text,
   evcontacts = cons
};



using (var db= new DatabaseModel())
{
   db.Evnts.Add(evnt);
   db.SaveChanges();
}
```

This code works fine if there are no events that are created with that user, but if I add the user to an event and then remove the user this does not work. How can I fix that?

Comment: I would suggest running a check and see if the contact is a member of any events.. if not, then remove. otherwise, you are deleting an account that has a reference in another table. Another suggestion is to remove that user from all events its a member of .. then delete contact.

Comment: Could you post the code the sequence that you mentioned here (adding user to event and then deleting). Also, please post error message.

Comment: @sam I edited the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is a Foreign Key and you have record - it needs to be deleted first (the operation on Event-contacts needs to be first) and then try removing Contacts.

```
using (var db= new DatabaseModel())
{
     Contact contact = db.Contacts.Find(id);
     if(contact != null){
     EventContact eventContact = db.EventContacts.Where(x=>x.contactId == 
        contact.Id).ToList();
      foreach(var item in eventVContact){
        db.contact.Remove(item);
        db.SaveChanges();
       }
     }
     if(eventContact?.Any()??true){
      db.Contact.Remove(contact);
      db.SaveChanges();
     }

}
```

Comment: I added the Contact to the context and then ran it, this worked so I accepted this as the answer. Thanks!!!